# IIS 8.5 re-directing to wrong site when using https

Tags: redirect, iis-8.5

I've got a weird problem with a server running IIS.

The server is running a number of websites (on different IP addresses), some of these use SSL and some don't.  The problem comes when you try to access a website using https when that site doesn't have any bindings for https.  The server automatically re-directs to another site on the server  that does have https (always the same site on it's own IP address).  There are no URL re-write rules and no special config that I can see anywhere.  I've tried to put in a re-write rule as a test for one of the sites, but it just gets ignored.  I'm unable to see how it's managing to do this.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bindings on the websites are all set to not have an asterisk on the IP Address. This is the default behavior for the Default Web Site in IIS.

Comment: All of the websites on the server have IP addresses specified - none are set to the default with an asterisk.